# How to disable content negotiation for Spring Actuators?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, content-negotiation

I'd like to disable Content-Negotiation when actuator endpoints `/info` and `/health` are called

here is my configs file

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    }
}
```

When I `curl http://localhost:8081/health`

I receive:

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

However when I fire same url in Chrome, i receive a valid response.

In my case actuator should be called without headers (no -H 'Accept: ...')

Comment: does `configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true)` fit your need ?

Comment: no, I still need to be able send GET requests with headers e.g. -H 'Accept: application/json' and xml

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add `defaultContentTypeStrategy` and handle the null or wildcard accept.

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    configurer.defaultContentTypeStrategy(new ContentNegotiationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public List<MediaType> resolveMediaTypes(NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
            // If you want handle different cases by getting header with webRequest.getHeader("accept")
            return Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
    });       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just overrides default content type, which is set to be XML `configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can only offer a suboptimal solution.

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
            .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .defaultContentTypeStrategy((webRequest) -> {
                final String servletPath = ((HttpServletRequest) webRequest.getNativeRequest()).getServletPath();
                final MediaType defaultContentType = Arrays.asList("/info", "/health").contains(servletPath)
                        ? MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON : MediaType.APPLICATION_XML;
                return Collections.singletonList(defaultContentType);
            });
}
```

In case the `/info` or `/health` endpoints get called `application/json` is returned. On all other requests the default `application/xml` is used.